# Sortable doesn't recognize inserted elements

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a two-level deep Sortable (jQuery) lists of the following structure. Both ul-elements and li-elements are sortable.

```
<div id="container">    
    <ul id="x_one">
        <li class="y_one"></li>
        <li class="y_two"></li>
        <li class="y_three"></li>
    </ul>
    <ul id="x_two">
        <li class="y_four"></li>
        <li class="y_five"></li>
        <li class="y_six"></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

When I dynamically insert (prepend) an additional ul element, like this:

```
<div id="container">    
    <ul id="x_three">

    </ul>
    <ul id="x_one">
        <li class="y_one"></li>
        <li class="y_two"></li>
        <li class="y_three"></li>
    </ul>
    <ul id="x_two">
        <li class="y_four"></li>
        <li class="y_five"></li>
        <li class="y_six"></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

I cannot drag li-elements onto the ul#x_three before refreshing the page.

How can inserted elements like these be recognized by jQuery's Sortable?

jQuery code:

```
$('#container').sortable({    
  update: function() {
   $.post($(this).data('update-url'), $(this).sortable('serialize'));
  }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mvhB4/2/

Comment: could you please add your javascript code to question?

Comment: after you insert new element, call .sortable() again.

Comment: maybe http://api.jqueryui.com/sortable/#method-refresh

Comment: first of all, how r u getting serialize to work for nested sortable elements?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you add items to the sortable yourself (rather than by dragging and dropping within the sortable), they don't have the attached event code necessary to operate. You fix this by calling `'refresh'` on your container:

```
$('#container').sortable('refresh');
```

The jQuery UI docs for [refresh in the Sortable Widget](http://api.jqueryui.com/sortable/#method-refresh) say:

> refresh()
>
> Refresh the sortable items. Triggers the reloading of all sortable items, causing new items to be recognized.
>
> This method does not accept any arguments.

**Update**

I'm sorry that I missed before the two-level sorting you were doing (I confess I haven't actually worked with sortables before). The fiddle was extremely helpful--I recommend creating one for every Javascript question!

The problem is that since you are making sortable not just the `<ul>` elements in the #container `<div>`, but also the `<li>` elements underneath them--and using `connectWith` to make them cross-list movable--when you add the new `<ul>`, it needs to be made sortable and wasn't (and it is also not part of the `connectWith` groups). So it is as simple as performing your initialization code all over again:

```
$('.list_type').sortable({
     connectWith: '.list_type'
});
```

And you are done. [It works (JsFiddle)](http://jsfiddle.net/mvhB4/3/).

Comment: I've tried exactly that, but the inserted element still doesn't get recognized: http://jsfiddle.net/mvhB4/2/